# Help with using Boolean modifier to subtract from a cube

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to subtract the Barium object from a cube to effectively create the inverse surface using Boolean modifier --> Subtract but can't seem to get it to work.

How would I go about doing this?

[image]

[image: SS of the object]

Comment: It does nothing because Bariums are dupli. After converting it to 'real mesh', Bariums will be non manifold (and boolean don't like that). But anyway I think there is far too much elements here to apply a boolean operation.

Comment: @jo416 It might be useful to edit the title to be more specific. Maybe "Using boolean modifier with overlapping spheres"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution i can think of which avoids doing many many boolean operations is to **use a Metaball** as dupli object instead of the Nurbs-Ball you are using. Metaballs will automatically "Stick together" and form a nice single combined volume (Which you can easily use for later boolean operations). If you go into edit mode and do the scaling of the metaball surface tension, you can get something like this:

[image]

When you are happy with the result you can select the parent object ("barium") make **duplicates real (Ctrl+Shift+A)**, convert the metaballs to mesh ("**Curve to mesh**", Alt+C in Blender 2.79b) and **then do a boolean operation**: (for some reason you need to apply a remesh modifier and triangulate the resulting mesh for the boolean to work properly... see images)

[image]

Happy Blending! :)